# Can't remove Phone permission to app

Tags: permissions

I'm trying to remove the **Phone** permission from this app ([Pango פנגו](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unicell.pangoandroid)) - but it just doesn't work!

I deny it, and it just comes back:

[image]

**What I tried:**

- Clearing data of the app
- Re-installing
- Disable all permissions (still phone comes back)

Any idea? It's so weird.
*Details: LG G5, stock, no root, Android 7.0*

Comment: Maybe enable the stock phone app to be default phone app, and then try again. If not, uninstall the app, reinstall.

Comment: The phone app is set to default, and already tried to re-install - still nothing :(